# how to write test case for rest service in scala akka(spray)

Tags: java, scala, rest, akka, spray

How to mock HttpRespose? I am using scalla, akka with spray for calling rest service which respond with json, I need to write test case for same. suggest me the technology that can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option would be to use *Spray Test Kit*
http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-testkit/ which comes with predefined methods which allow for some mocking.

If you need to mock an underlaying library *Mockito* is a grat choice but there are others like *Scalamock* you could give a try.

For JSON checking I had good experience with using spray's json library and checking on the deserialized object.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito is still for me the best mock-utility (see http://site.mockito.org/). It's written for and in java, but I find it works very well with scala. Another good one is easymock (http://easymock.org/).

You should also evaluate whether you need to go so low as mocking HttpResponse or if you can let your tests operate on a higher level than that.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer to the title:

> how to write test case for rest service in scala akka(spray)

It looks like there are missing points in the detailed description of the question...

It worth to mention that there are different levels of tests we usually write and I would suggest the following:

- for unit tests (no actor specific) mocking there many options that not different from usual suspects we have in java ([Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/), [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/)) + some scala specific (like [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/)). [Scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/) provides a sugar wrapper for some of them so I would recommend it.
- on integration tests level I would mention [akka-testkit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#Asynchronous_Integration_Testing_with_TestKit) which is the best option to verify actors behaviour by exchanging messages. Also as mentioned in previous answer there is [spray-testkit](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-testkit/) which makes testing of route logic easy.
- for service/component level tests (send http request and verify the http response) you can use any usual testing library like Scalatest or use more complicated one for writing business oriented tests like [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/). There are also some options to mock/stub dependencies like: [mock-server](http://www.mock-server.com/#what-is-mockserver), [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/), [stubby4j](https://stubby4j.com) which actually can be used in any language but the question mentions scala so jvm running options should be preferable. From my experience mock-server is the most flexible option here.